# Joining tables and recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following tables.
Articles, Categories, ArticleCategories

Each article can have multiple categories.
The problem is that database is designed in a way where Category contains ParentCategoryId, and article does not need to be connected with a root category, but actually is part of it, since it belongs to one of its child categories.

Example

Categories

1. CategoryId 1, ParentCategory 0
2. Category2, ParentCategory 1
3. Category 3, ParentCategory 2

Article

1. Id = 1

ArticleCategories

1. ArticleId = 1, CategoryId = 3

Now, what i need is a way to list articles with their root category (categories which have ParentID = 0).
Returned dataset would have ArticleID and RootCategoryId (no need for child categories)

I started with

```
SELECT 
ar.Id, 
ar.Title, 
ac.CategoryId,
ca.Name FROM Article ar
INNER JOIN ArticleCategories ac
ON ar.Id = ac.ArticleId
INNER JOIN Categories ca
ON ca.CategoryId = ac.CategoryId
```

But this is obviously just a query to join article with existing categories, not their root categories.
I guess i need some kind of recursion to reach root category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate the root categories using a recursive cte:

```
with cr as (
      select c.categoryid, c.categoryid as root_categoryid
      from categories c
      where c.parentcategoryid = 0
      union all
      select c.categoryid, cr.root_categoryid
      from categories c join
           cr
           on c.patentcategoryid = cr.categoryid
    )
select *
from cr;
```

You can then use this to join in the parent categories (you seem to understand how to join things together, so this answer just focuses on the recursive CTE part).

Comment: why do you 2x select c.categoryid in the first select statement?

Comment: @Robert . . . One is for the category id and the other for the root category id.